# Angular prod performance bundle css in .js or in .css?

Tags: angular

I'm wondering what's the best way to improve
performance in an angular app.
When I run 
build --prod
is it a good practice to add --extract-css
build --prod --extract-css

Comment: I accept the downvote but I'd like to know what's wrong with my question ^^

Comment: Why would they default to the non optimized solution?

Comment: That I want to know :) without my style.js is 1M with is about 150k so it seems better

Comment: That's because it's the optimized way of doing this... It was not a question.

Comment: usually after "optimized way of doing this" should be an explanation ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, is to clarify your question :

"extract-css" will help you separate file for css alone, thus more readable.

However with default which is false, all will be bundled inside one js file only and hence less number of network calls.

Just to reduce no. of network calls, **bundling** is done.

Comment: @user3887366 does this clarify your question?

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer so using --extract-css improve performance ?

Comment: So you will see many post saying extracting css out you can cache those, this will only be possible if output hashing is set to false, else everytime a new hash will be generated and hence it will not be cached, however you can cache it as well as per your requirements. Now if you don’t extract css separately, you will only be doing 1 network call which is minified and optimized and hence less traffic thus faster loading. So in short, default value which is false is optimized and serve you better performance.

Comment: Does this clarify your question now?